# Boolean multiplication in c++?

Tags: c++, boolean, ternary-operator, standards-compliance

Consider the following:

```
inline unsigned int f1(const unsigned int i, const bool b) {return b ? i : 0;}
inline unsigned int f2(const unsigned int i, const bool b) {return b*i;}
```

The syntax of `f2` is more compact, but do the standard guarantees that `f1` and `f2` are strictly equivalent ?

Furthermore, if I want the compiler to optimize this expression if `b` and `i` are known at compile-time, which version should I prefer ?

Comment: You can't know what "the compiler" will do with the expression (in the case of compile-time-known arguments) without specifying which compiler, but it is likely to optimize both away.  One way to tell, compile each with compile-time-known arguments and inspect the output.

Comment: Look at the generated assembly code

Comment: FWIW, MSVC generates a mask and add for the first case, and a multiply for the second, in a case where I prevented it playing tricks with the evaluation of the boolean itself (if it can, it will change the test that produces the bool in order to optimise further). Essentially, MSVC is branchless in either case, and seems more optimal in the naive case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I multiply an int with a boolean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142145/can-i-multiply-an-int-with-a-boolean-in-c)

Comment: You can multiply an `int` and `bool`. At higher warning levels you sometimes get a performance warning. Usually you convert the `bool` to an `int` with `!!`: `return (!!b)*i;`. That will keep the compiler happy when it complains.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, yes, both are equivalent. `bool` is an integral type and `true` is guaranteed to convert to `1` in integer context, while `false` is guaranteed to convert to `0`.

(The reverse is also true, i.e. non-zero integer values are guaranteed to convert to `true` in boolean context, while zero integer values are guaranteed to convert to `false` in boolean context.)

Since you are working with unsigned types, one can easily come up with other, possibly bit-hack-based yet perfectly portable implementations of the same thing, like

```
i & -(unsigned) b
```

although a decent compiler should be able to choose the best implementation by itself for any of your versions.

P.S. Although to my great surprise, GCC 4.1.2 compiled all three variants virtually literally, i.e. it used machine multiplication instruction in multiplication-based variant. It was smart enough to use `cmovne` instruction on the `?:` variant to make it branchless, which quite possibly made it the most efficient implementation.

Comment: How, exactly, is your "bit-hack" a "perfectly portable implementation"? The Standard does not mandate two's-complement representation for signed integers (at least not yet), so if ported to a system that doesn't use that, it would fall apart in bizarre ways. Also, as you showed, a good compiler would do such platform-specific hacks while optimising, rather than requiring users to  mess up their code with such low-level details and assumptions.

Comment: @underscore_d: What are you talking about? Where do you see "signed integers" in the above code and where exactly do you see the dependency on two's-complement representation? Are you talking about unary `-`? The behavior of unary `-` in unsigned context does not depend on signed representation.

Comment: You're right; I must have been half asleep... I was just after commenting a similar thing on another answer that *did* cast the `bool` to a signed `int`, and I didn't notice you were doing it differently and properly.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It's safe to assume `true` is `1` and `false` is `0` when used in expressions as you do and is guaranteed:

**C++11, Integral Promotions, 4.5**:

> An rvalue of type bool can be converted to an rvalue of type int, with
>   false becoming zero and true becoming one.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will use implicit conversion to make an `unsigned int` from `b`, so, yes, this should work. You're skipping the condition checking by simple multiplication. Which one is more effective/faster? Don't know. A good compiler would most likely optimize both versions I'd assume.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the following code

```
inline unsigned int f1(const unsigned int i, const bool b) {return b ? i : 0;}
inline unsigned int f2(const unsigned int i, const bool b) {return b*i;}

int main()
{
    volatile unsigned int i = f1(42, true);
    volatile unsigned int j = f2(42, true);
}
```

compiled with gcc -O2 produces this assembly:

```
    .file   "test.cpp"
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .text.startup,"x"
    .p2align 2,,3
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $42, 8(%esp)   // i
    movl    $42, 12(%esp)  // j
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE2:
```

There's not much left of either `f1` or `f2`, as you can see.

As far as C++ standard is concerned, the compiler is allowed to do anything with regards to optimization, as long as it doesn't change the observable behaviour (the *as if* rule).

Comment: To produce a representative result, you should probably use non-predictable (by the compiler) arguments to the function `f1(rand(), rand())` would be a better example.