# Can I multiply an int with a boolean in C++?

Tags: c++, int, boolean

I have a widget in my GUI that displays chart(s). If I have more than one chart there will be a legend shown in a rectangle on the GUI.

I have a `QStringlist (legendText)` which holds the text of the legend. If there is no legend required, `legendText` would be empty. If there will be a legend, `legendText` would hold the text.

For finding the height of the rectangle around the legend I would like to do the following:

```
 int height = 10;
 QStringList legendText;
 ...
 height = height * (legendText->size() > 0);
 ...
```

Is this a good idea/ good style to multiply an `int` with a `boolean`? Will I run into problems with that?

Comment: It seems to me that this question is about style and legibility, while the alleged duplicate concerns optimisation.

Comment: You can, but you are sacrificing readability. I would prefer to make my intent explicit.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you assign `height` in the first place, if you might be just about to cancel it. This is confusing and also hinders `const`-correctness. Why not just `int const height = 10 * (legendText->size() > 0);` or `int const height = legendText->isEmpty() ? 0 : 10;` (or any of the other possible variations)?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This is technically fine, if a bit unclear.

The `bool` will be *promoted* to an `int`, so the result is well-defined. However, looking at that code I don't instantly get the semantics you are trying to achieve.

I would simply write something like:

```
height = legendText->isEmpty() ? 0 : height;
```

This makes your intent far clearer.

Comment: I'd reduce it further to just `if (legendText->empty()) height = 0;`. That's the usual way to write this.

Answer (score 31):

It's perfectly fine according to the standard (§4.5/6):

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with
>   `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

However, I suggest using `isEmpty` instead of comparing `size` to zero `height = height * (!legendText->isEmpty());`

Or use the conditional operator as the other answers suggest (but still with `isEmpty` instead of `.size() > 0`)

Comment: I like the branch-free approach of multiplying by `!legendText->isEmpty()`.

Comment: @RandallCook Which machine, specifically, are you optimising for? Conditional move instructions are fairly common nowadays, which make both options branch-free.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the conditional (ternary) operator:

```
height = ( legendText->size() >0 ) ? height : 0 ;
```

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this?

```
if(legendText->isEmpty())
{
   height = 0;
}
```

or

```
int height = legendText->isEmpty() ? 0 : 10;
```

Comment: Add `const` to that and you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

Some people may find following information useful (following code should be considered in high performance programs where every clock cycle matters and it's purpose here is to show alternative techniques, I wouldn't use it in this particular situation).

If you need fast code without branches you can implement int multiplication with boolean using bitwise operators.

```
bool b = true;
int  number = 10;
number = b*number;
```

can be optimized to:

```
number = (-b & number);
```

If `b` is `true` then `-b` is `-1` and all bits are set to `1`. Otherwise all bits are `0`.
Boolean NOT (`!b`) can be implemented by XOR'ing `b` with `1` (`b^1`).
So in your case we get following expression:

```
height = (-(legendText->isEmpty()^1) & height);
```

Comment: If you need fast code you can *tell your compiler to optimize your code* . That's what compilers do.   Your code would fail on a non 2's complement system.

Comment: Compilers perform only simple optimizations. They will not do the work for you. They would have to understand the code and we are not there yet.

Comment: "Your code would fail on a non 2's complement system". Such systems are very rare...

Comment: The (arguably) most-readable version `if (legendText->isEmpty()) height = 0;` is already compiled to branch-free machine code by multiple popular compilers even when only minimal optimisations are enabled. Your answer is already only useful for rare systems.

Comment: Yes, this code shouldn't be used in this particular situation. This answer is more about presenting alternative techniques which might be useful in high performance programs.